# How to write sub query with where Condition and match the columns values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

the following is my query

```
select * from tbl_incometax_master where (select Slabtitle=Gender,SlabSubTitle=Senior_CTZN_Type FROM etds.dbo.tbl_Employee_Master WHERE employee_id = 1218  AND company_id = 1987)
```

when try to execute got following error in sql server 2008 r2 :
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you intend to do (Uses `EXISTS`):

```
select *
from tbl_incometax_master
where exists (
        select 1
        from etds.dbo.tbl_Employee_Master
        where employee_id = 1218
            and company_id = 1987
            and Slabtitle = Gender
            and SlabSubTitle = Senior_CTZN_Type
        )
```

It's a correlated subquery, where the outer query checks if there is at least one row exists in the subquery for current row.

Comment: Thanks for reply GurV, but query doesn't  return any rows.

Comment: @user2561115 - Post sample data and expected output in your question then

Answer (score 1):

You dont have any column in where clause of parent query, it is important to know that only column criteria can be defined with subquery.

Sample query...

```
 select * from tbl_incometax_master where <column> (select <subquery column> FROM etds.dbo.tbl_Employee_Master WHERE employee_id = 1218  AND company_id = 1987)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Bilal, i know about this. but if i want to do this with multiple columns in sub query with same table which i used in sub query for one col and other columns condition.

Comment: Another option is mention by GurV

Answer (score 0):

You have a select clause in your Where with no operator (=,<,>,IN) ! And '=' inside the Select! 
None of them are allowed in a SQL Query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tbl_incometax_master table1 LEFT JOIN 
(
select Gender,Senior_CTZN_Type FROM etds.dbo.tbl_Employee_Master WHERE     employee_id = 1218  AND company_id = 1987
) table2
ON 
table1.Slabtitle=table2.Gender
AND table1.SlabSubTitle=table2.Senior_CTZN_Type
WHERE table2.Slabtitle IS NOT NULL
```